# Is there a feature to 'show datatips' in Spyder?

Tags: spyder, datatip

in Matlab there is an option called '**enable datatips in edit mode**', which gives you the capability to hover with a mouse over a variable in your code, and see it's content.

Is there something similar in Python (Spyder IDE)?

Thank You!

Comment: The question is more about the Spyder tool than about Python. I would advice to change the title and tags according to this removing "python" from both. In this way you can get only visitors with experience in Spyder

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Unfortunately we don't have such an option, sorry.

Comment: Is there any intention to add it in some future version? It is VERY (VERY!!!) useful.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. We'll consider it for a future release.